# href must not reload

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am testing the following link:

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

But, as expected, it reloads my current page. How can I prevent it from reloading the page, but maintaining the *-a-* tag assigned to it?

Thanks ;)

Comment: You can do this : `<a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you don't want it to behave like a link, then don't use a link tag. Doing so hurt accessibility of a page, and you don't want that. There are other ways of browsing a website than a browser (think about the screen readers), which relies on the semantics of the page elements. Use a `span` if you simply want to apply a style.

If you still want to use an anchor, you can use this -

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">Link</a>
```

This will prevent your page reloading.

Comment: I was going to answer the same, but I think he is using `base` tag and that's what causing to reload

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought earlier, just needed the opinion. thanks! :D

Comment: hi guys, but what about if you want for example to add something in url like a parameter href="?selected_user={{user.id}}" but you don´t want the page to be refreshed?

Comment: I have added a new question expanding the scenario here. Please reply if you know the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69264347/add-url-to-href-on-a-tag-but-do-not-want-to-reload-behavior

Answer (score 45):

Just add javascript:void(0) in href you will get..

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
```

Comment: For security precaution reasons it's not encouraged to inject javascript inside url.

Answer (score 7):

I think `javascript:;` also works.

```
<a href="javascript:;">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply don't specify `href` attribute:

```html
<a>Link</a>
```

A link without `href`...

- does not reload a page on click
- does not change cursor to `pointer` on hover
- does not change text style to `underlined`

Comment: I think, he is using <a> precisely because of these things: pointing cursor and underlined blue text. Otherwise he wouldn't ask this question and use another tag