# Add url to href on <a> tag but do not want to reload behavior

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, anchor

The following code opens the anchor tag on a new window
However, I do not want to reload the parent page. And also I want to have the ability to Open in a new tab on mouse right click (image below)

[image]

If I use `href = {'javascript:'}` it prevents the parent page from reloading however, when clicked on "Open in a new Tab", it opens on a new tab but url becomes `about:blank#blocked`

```
const handleClick = () => {
      window.open(
        href,
        'newwindow',
        `width=${window.outerWidth * 0.5}, height=${
          window.outerHeight
        }, left = ${window.outerWidth * 0.25} `
      );
      return false;
  };

<a href = {href} onClick = {handleClick}> This is Url </a>
```

**Desired result:**

- By default, open in a new window.
- Prevent parent window from refreshing.
- Have ability to open on new tab on right click.

Comment: When you right click, you do not want the menu to show up? Directly open new tab?

Comment: I want menu to show up and also be clickable and pointed to the right url. If I pass url to  `<a href = {href} > </a>` This reload the page. I don't want page to reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `target="_blank"` for this.

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To open the link in a new window or a new tab, you can use the target attribute in your anchor tag i.e. `<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">...</a>`